# Define this limit

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits

$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=∞.$

If someone could give me a definition for that I would be eternally thankful.  So far I have for any $N>0$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $0<x-a<\delta$, then $f(x)>N$.  Is this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition is:

> For all $N>0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that if $0 < \lvert x - a \rvert
>  < \delta$ then $f(x) > N$.

It looks like the limit you have written is the definition of the right-side limit. Note that $0 < \lvert x - a \rvert < \delta$ is equivalent to $-\delta < x-a < \delta$ and $x\neq a$.

Comment: Yea, I couldn't really get the absolute values on the keyboard I was working on, so like every mathematician, I just decided to be lazy for once in a while.

Comment: @jack: Don't be lazy in math ... :)

Comment: I know but its so tempting sometimes

Comment: There's always $\operatorname{abs}(x-a)$.